# DNA sequence data - requirement for a long and wide table of experimental data

Tags: database-design

I need to build a database to hold data obtained from DNA sequencing experiments.

1) 5 million columns of data in one sample, and hundreds of samples in total

2) A few data points are null

3) Calculate the median, standard deviation etc. of each column every week

What would be an optimal design for this data and help to shorten the time consumed in analysis?

Any suggestion(s) would be appreciated.

---

Data type: DNA sequencing data. Break the whole chromosome into 1kb windows and calculate the mean depths of sequencing etc.

Columns: bed1, bed2...bed10000...

Rows: sample1, sample2...

---

Even if the focus is only on genes, there would be several thousand columns.

I wonder if there is any tool or solution to hand.

Comment: Welcome to [dba stack exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) it is a very interesting experiment, however for this forum generally the questions need to have more focus and not be opinion based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is what you suggest a standard method of storing DNA sequencing results? Apart from the technical difficulties - good luck finding a database that will allow that many columns (SciDB?) - it will make querying tricky. I would look into ways of having your tables be tall and skinny rather than short and fat.

I would do something like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE sample
(
  bed INTEGER NOT NULL,
  sample_no INTEGER NOT NULL,
  ..
  .. other fields? 
  .. chromosomal location? sequence? phenotype? 
  .. dna_type (gene | promoter | mRNA | tRNA... &c.)?
  ..
  CONSTRAINT sample_pk PRIMARY KEY (bed, sample_no)
);
```

I believe that such a schema will facilitate querying and be far more technically feasible - it will conform far better to the relational model and will ultimately save you a lot of grief! I asked above `Is this a standard method of storing DNA sequencing results?` - this work has been done before so why are you reinventing the wheel?

Don't get me wrong - I'm all in favour of experimenting and trying to get a new perspective on biological phenomena, that's what science/molecular biology is all about, but others must have done this before - you may want to look at their work? For the record, I have a Masters in Cellular and Molecular Genetics from the Univeristé de Paris. HTH...

Comment: Thanks. I do not know much about databases. And this kind of data used to be stored in 
.txt files. And take time to read and analyse. The original data is much bigger and will not be put into the database.

Comment: My approach would be to put all of your data into a db - PostgreSQL, then remove any extraneous stuff and then you have your working set (AIUI, that's the way it works - these sequencing machines produce a lot of data which is processed and then you can "throw away" a lot of the "raw" data?). I would then archive my original data (you never know) on cheap tape or whatever storage and work with your processed data. It's in the data processing that databases will start to shine with respect to text files - a comparison would be stone tablets to pen and paper - HTH! p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: The toolkits dealing with the original data has nothing to do with the database. So as long as the data could be stored in the db, a part of them have been thrown away. By the way, what's the meaning of AIUI and HTH? LOL

Comment: AIUI = As I Understand It - HTH = Hope This Helps! You could start by taking a subset of your data and trying my suggestion as well as that of Michael Green. It's been a while since I've been in the Genetics game, so maybe my advice is off-base?

Comment: Really great advice. The operation is not as easy as before for me. It may take some time to learn it.

Comment: If you found it helpful, you can upvote me and/or mark my answer as correct! It might help others with a similar requirement - I'll edit the question to include something about DNA in the subject?

Comment: If you are working with few columns at a time, you may want to look into a columnar store. It appears to exists for PostgreSQL, though I know nothing about that. From other vendors I've seen some impressive improvements for analytical queries involving few columns.

Comment: @Lennart - indeed - it's actually an extension by citusdata - might very well be worth investigating and, as you say, this sort of data my well be ideal for this type of store! Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Five million columns? Nah. Taking a column as a relational database term it represents a single, atomic fact distinct from and not overlapping with any other fact about the single *thing* (row) in question. I could believe the are 5M measurements on one thing, but not separate, distinct facts.

If you want to do this in a relational DB  (Postgres, SQL Server, etc.) it is better to calculate aggregates over rows. The tables would then look like

```
Sample (sample_id, source, ...)
Bed (sample_id, bed_number, ...)
```

This will give you a few hundred milion rows in Bed. Any recent hardware will be able to handle that.

There are software products specifically designed to operate on DNA type values. I'm not expert enough to advise. I will mention that bioinformatics.stackexchange.com exists. You're more likely to find specific knowledge there.

Some of the NoSQL products may be able to hold all 5M values in a singke "row." However, it is unlikely there will be built-in functions to perform calculations across "columns".

Comment: Thanks. I am an outsider of the database. And the online materials are mainly about the techniques and codes. The 1st paragraph is much helpful.